# Blank page when I deploy on Render due to Material UI Pagination

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I implemented MUI's pagination because Chakra UI doesn't have one. I deployed my app on render and I get a blank page, but there's no blank page on localhost. If I remove the pagination along with the other MUI stuff, the project displays perfectly. This is the error I see

[image]

This is how I implemented the MUI's pagination

```js
import TablePagination from "@mui/material/TablePagination";
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material";

const defaultMaterialTheme = createTheme();

const Customers = () => {
const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(10);

  const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
    setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
    setPage(0);
  };
  
  return(
  <ThemeProvider theme={defaultMaterialTheme}>
        <TablePagination
          sx={{
            "& .MuiTablePagination-spacer": {
              order: 2,
            },
            "& .MuiTablePagination-selectLabel": {
              order: 0,
            },
            "& .MuiTablePagination-select": {
              order: 1,
            },
            "& .MuiTablePagination-displayedRows": {
              order: 3,
            },
            "& .MuiTablePagination-actions": {
              order: 4,
            },
          }}
          component="div"
          count={customers.length}
          page={page}
          onPageChange={handleChangePage}
          rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
          rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 30, 50]}
          onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Card>
  );
};
```